# EAGLE PCB Delete all nets in a selected area

Tags: eaglecad

I have a section in my schematic which is full of shenanigans. I want to delete all the nets in the selected box with a single command. Is it possible? I mean only delete nets and not anything else:

[image]

If I have to do it manually  I have to click 1 million times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to That different nets have different names you cannot delete all of them in one command.
You can use the group function to select the unwanted group of nets, and select the delete command then right click on your schematic page and select delete group.

Answer (score 1):

Hide all Layers but Nets Layer, select all the nets you want to get rid of, delete...